# Help me refind this 3d go variant - pieces can be stacked in a pyramid fashion

Tags: identify-this-game, go, variants

Quite a while back I stumbled upon a 3D variant of the game go. What I recall of the rules:

- designed to be playable without extra equipment beyond go board and stones
- played on a 9x9 grid
- stones can be stacked by putting one piece above/between 4 pieces, forming a little pyramid
- capturing stones works within one plane as normal, except that stones under other stones are pinched and can't be captured

The whole ruleset is online somewhere. However my google fu is weak and with the terms go, weiqi, baduk, 3d and pyramid I had no luck. I also found no mention while skimming [this reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/baduk/comments/2h3aij/question_who_has_looked_into_3d_versions_of_go/) or [this entry in the sensei's library](http://senseis.xmp.net/?UnusualGobans).

Comment: This sounds to me like it is taking some inspiration from [Mahjong solitaire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahjong_solitaire). This may or may not help your googling efforts, but "mahjong" will potentially drown out any go-related results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like it might be [***Margo***](http://www.cameronius.com/games/margo/), except that Margo is played on a 7X7 grid, not 9X9. Per the linked website by Cameron Browne:

> Two players, White and Black, each have at least enough marbles of
>   their colour to cover the board.
>
> **Start**: The board is initially empty. White places the first piece at
>   any board point, then Black may elect to swap colours in lieu of
>   making the next move (swap rule).
>
> **Play**: Players then take turns placing a piece of their colour either:
>              1) at an empty board point, or 
>              2) stacked on top of four existing pieces (of any colour).
>
> Players may not pass.

The capture rules sound like what you describe, and I think the "pinched" stones at the bottom of "pyramids" are what the rules refer to as

> **Pinned Pieces**: When a group is captured, any of its pieces pinned by higher-level enemy pieces remain in place. For example, move c captures the following White group but leaves two pinned pieces.

Comment: yes, that's it. misremembered a few aspects.